# Adding new column and its value based on file name

Tags: r

I have 10 data files in my current directory such as `data-01`, `data-02`, `data-03`, `data-04` till `data-10`.

Each of these data files has a few hundred rows with 4 fields. I would like to add a new column name "ID" and keep its ID like `01` (for data file `data-01`) for all the rows in that file.

Comment: I usually do `library(data.table); LF = list.files(pattern="csv$"); rbindlist(lapply(setNames(LF,LF), fread), idcol = "source")` if the fields are the same across the files. This stacks the data and makes a "source" column containing the file name associated with each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A base R solution using a loop would go like this:

```
df<- c()
for (x in list.files(pattern="*.csv")) {
  u<-read.table(x)
  u$Label = factor(x)
  df <- rbind(df, u)
  cat(x, "\n ")
}
```

This depends on your data files having the same number of columns (though you get get around that inside the loop by selecting which columns you need before `rbind`) and then you can set whichever filetype you are looking at. The `cat` is useful because you can better trace read problems (because there are always problems). I bet there is a better way to do this with `apply` as well.